# Email message disappears from my inbox when I forward the message

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2011

In Outlook 2011 for Mac, I have email messages being removed from the inbox when I forward the message to someone.

The only place I seem to find the message afterwards is in the sent file. How can I have them remain in the inbox so that I may file them as I see fit?

Comment: Have a look around the "view" settings of Outlook. You may have inadvertently set your inbox to only show "unread" messages. When you forward a message it is technically marked as "read" so Outlook (according to your view settings) makes the message disappear. Reset the view and you should see all your messages (read + unread) together.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook on Windows has an option to keep a copy of sent email ONLY in **subfolders** of Inbox - not inbox itself - this is also prone to malfunction (with PST files at least); so you may need to pick it up from 'sent mail' anyway.

It is a setting in 'Tools > Options' somewhere (out of memory).